# Is it possible to remove an entire set after some time in Redis?

Tags: database, redis, set

i'm new to Redis and i'm trying to use it to save the results from query's so i don't have to access the API every time. 
Now, let's suppose i have a query that brings me names so, every time a name comes as a result from the API i save it in Redis, so after 10 query's i have a set in Redis that has all of this values [John, Joseph, Nick...], can i remove the entire set after let's say ... an hour? 
I would like to delete all of the values from that set in one go.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Redis' [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire) command - it does exactly that. For example, if your Set is stored at the 'myset' key, this will expire it after one hour:

```
redis> EXPIRE myset 3600
```

Comment: Thanks! i just tried that and apparently it works the way i want to